# undefined method for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm building an invoice application and in the `_form` partial i made the invoice where users can add products including quantity, description and unitprice. And users can add extra rows to add more items(products).

Now when i try to display that information in the show view like this:

```
    <tbody>
     <tr class="products_tr">
      <td> <%= @invoice.products.quantity %> </td>
      <td> <%= @invoice.products.description %> </td>
      <td> <%= @invoice.products.unitprice %> </td>
      <td class="row_total"><%= @invoice.products.quantity * @invoice.products.unitprice %></td>
      <td> <%= @invoice.products.btw %> </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**it gives out the next error:**

```
undefined method `quantity' for #<Product::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fbe92831500>
```

This is the code in the controller;

```
  def show
    @invoice.products.build
    @invoice.build_customer
  end
```

Any idea on how to fix this? help would be much appreciated. And plus points for an explanation on what it is exactly that i'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

If i loop through the @invoice.products like Michał Młoźniak said it works but it also shows an extra row that contains nil, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said yourself that invoice can have many products so you need a loop to iterate over this list of products.

```
<tbody>
  <% @invoice.products.each do |product| %>
    <% if product.persisted? %>
      <tr class="products_tr">
        <td> <%= product.quantity %> </td>
        <td> <%= product.description %> </td>
        <td> <%= product.unitprice %> </td>
        <td class="row_total"><%= product.quantity * product.unitprice %></td>
        <td> <%= product.btw %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yeah i was thinking something like this aswell and it works fine but it also shows an extra row that contains nil. see picture in original post.

Comment: @luissimo Ok, I added additional check `if product.persisted?`. This will only display products already saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

your `@invoice.products` is a collection where as you should calling `quantity` on each object in that collection.